# Can I convert JMeter Standalone file into GUI file?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

Currently, I'm working on the java project in which I can create/run JMeter. The test files generated from java code seemed working okay but the format is different from the file I used to make on JMeter GUI. I wonder it is possible to convert the JMeter standalone generated test file into JMeter GUI file. (I get an error message when I'm trying to open standalone file from JMeter GUI)

Answer (score 1):

How we're supposed to help without:

1. Seeing your code
2. Seeing the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) generated by code
3. Seeing the .jtl file generated by JMeter
4. Seeing the error message?

In general I don't think that creating JMeter test plans purely from Java is really officially supported, to my limited knowledge you should be using [JMeter GUI](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) for creating test plans.

There are some 3rd-party projects which provide possibility of creating a JMeter test programmatically like:

- [JMeter Ruby DSL](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter)
- [JMeter Java DSL](https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl)
- [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/)

This way you can get "JMeter-as-a-code" option without investing extra efforts in it.

Theoretically it's possible to use [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) for running a test plan from Java or even for building it from Java, you can check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article to learn more about the details

Also you can use [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/demo/JMeterFromScratch.java) project as the reference

However no one will give you the guarantee that the code will still be actual after release of the new version of JMeter.